# NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval repeat model will cause memory ascend

Tags: ios, swift

Recently, when check memory leak, found a phenomenon.
Use Instruments leaks, not found leaks, But always found live memory had ascend after some time.
The span of the rising time is related with scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval repeat time, so I code a demo. 
Why appear this phenomenon , if NStimer had allocated memory , but why the allocated memory will more and more ? 
Thanks

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let dic = ["1":"3"]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()        
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.2, target: self, selector: Selector("getList"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func getList() {
        DDLogInfo("\(dic.description)")
    }
  }
```

[xCode debug session live Memory Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOxG3.png)

Comment: Are you testing in the simulator? If so, forget about it; your test isn't meaningful. Don't worry unless the problem appears on the device using a release build.

Comment: ok, I get it, The repeat call DDLogInfo cause memory grow. thanks